# Is it possible to have SimpleHTTPServer serve files from two different directories?

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

If I do `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` it serves the files in the current directory.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
/protected/public
/protected/private
/test
```

I want to start the server in my `/test` directory and I want it to serve files in the `/test` directory.  But I want all requests to the server starting with '/public' to be pulled from the `/protected/public` directory.

e.g.a request to `http://localhost:8000/public/index.html` would serve the file at `/protected/public/index.html`

Is this possible with the built in server or will I have to write a custom one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe SimpleHTTPServer has this feature, however if you use a symbolic link inside of /test that points to /protected/public, that should effectively do the same thing.

Comment: As of Python 2.7, it doesn't seem to follow symlinks.

Comment: Never mind, it does handle symlinks -- it just doesn't autogenerate directory indexes for them.

Comment: Even more so, since you can actually write the code for the do_GET method, you can fetch any file from anywhere - or even generate your own contents.

Answer (score 16):

I think it is absolutely possible to do that. You can start the server inside `/test` directory and override `translate_path` method of `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` as follows:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
server_address = ("", 8888)
PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX = '/public'
PUBLIC_DIRECTORY = '/path/to/protected/public'

class MyRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def translate_path(self, path):
        if self.path.startswith(PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX):
            if self.path == PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX or self.path == PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX + '/':
                return PUBLIC_DIRECTORY + '/index.html'
            else:
                return PUBLIC_DIRECTORY + path[len(PUBLIC_RESOURCE_PREFIX):]
        else:
            return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.translate_path(self, path)

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(server_address, MyRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still works excellently, thanks! In my case, I used (referring to your code) `'public'` as the prefix, prepended `"/" +` before the prefix when checking the path, and added `+ 1` to the `len()` when returning. That made it a little more versatile, especially because I didn't want to mix the mandatory URL `/`'s with file paths that were otherwise all \'s. Also, Python auto-generated `return super().translate_path(path)` for me, instead of your last return. Oh and I should mention that I used `CGIHTTP...` and it still worked.

Answer (score 7):

I think I have found the answer to this, basically it involves changing the current working directory, starting the server and then returning back to your original working directory.

This is how I achieved it, I've commented out two sets of options for you, as the solution for me was just moving to a folder within my app directory and then back up one level to the original app directory. But, you might want to go to an entire other directory in your file system and then return someplace else or not at all.

```
#Setup file server
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import os

PORT = 5002

#  -- OPTION 1 --
#os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.curdir),'PATH_TO_FOLDER_IN_APP_DIR'))
#  -- OPTION 2 --
#os.chdir('PATH_TO_ROOT_DIRECTORY')

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()

#  -- OPTION 1 --
#os.chdir(os.path.abspath('..'))
#  -- OPTION 2 --
#os.chdir('PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_WORKING_DIR')
```

Let me know how it works out!

Comment: how would you get back to the folder if the script is "serving forever"?, i.e., it will not pass the line `httpd.serve_forever()`